# Sorting to query for database

Tags: sql, arrays, powershell

Trying to get the input to the variable and pass the value it to the sql query using array in PowerShell.

Please help me in understanding this

```
$value=read-host "Please enter the value:"
Invoke-sqlcmd -query "select * from something where somewhere in ($value)
```

As mentioned in the above example
I need the values entered to get pass through the sql query with every value should have sorted with punctuation.

Example

```
select * from something where somewhere in('1234','2345','3456')
```

Help me in retrieving the value and sorting it accordingly for query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the user inputs the values you have to first *split* the values to get an array. You probably want to split by one or multiple *whitespaces*:

```
$value - split '\s+'
```

Then you have to surround each value by a single quote using the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
$value -split '\s+' | ForEach-Object {"'$_'"}
```

And finally *join* the values by a comma. So you probably want to use something like this:

```
($value -split '\s+' | ForEach-Object {"'$_'"} ) -join ','
```

---

**Example**: if the user enters:

```
3 12 5
```

You will get

```
'3','12','5'
```

Comment: Thanks Martin !!!It worked great

One more help,Plz.

How to data-in more values in powershell and have it stored in variable and call it every time in a query

$value = read-host "Enter the value's" I need 15 values to be entered..

like $value[0]=1233 $value[1]=2345 . .

Comment: You are welcome. Please start a new question if you need further help, other ppl will thank you